# Не копируется элемент с одной формы на другую

Tags: c#, winforms

хочу выделить элемент с одной вин формы и скопировать на другую. однако, он копируется, но в другую форму не вставляется. не могу понять в чем дело. картинку прикладываю, "фио" и "выберите зачисление" копируются и вставляются а элемент "Приказ" нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проект не запущен?

Comment: нет, не запущен, выделение элемента происходит, проверял cut' ом. А вот в ставка в другую форму не происходит

Comment: ну а с других форм контроллы копируются?

Comment: с других я не смотрел, но с этой приказ не копируется

Comment: еще вопрос, это стандартные контролы или вы используете сторонюю библиотеку?

Comment: спасибо за наводку, форма не моя, сейчас посмотрю.